# Post data give me IntegrityError Django

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django, and I'm trying to post data -key and value for article using DRF:

```
class ArticalMetaData(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField()
    value = models.CharField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("content_type", "object_id", "key")


class MetaDataCreationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, content_object, *args, **kwargs):
        self.content_object = content_object
        super(MetaDataCreationSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = MetaData
        fields = ('key', 'value','content_object')
```

And this is the view:

```
    def create(self, request, pk=None):
    Artical = self.get_object()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = MetaDataCreationSerializer(data=request.data, content_object=Artical)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            metadata = serializer.save()
            metadata.content_object = Articla
            metadata.save()
            serializer = MetaDataSerializer(metadata)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

But this gives me this error:

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
null value in column "object_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: Can you include the data which you post? And what is the content_object in the serializer? Can you include the part of code ( view ) where do you actually use the serializer ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an existing database which have values of `object_id` as null. And then you updated the `unique_together` field. So the existing data does not match with the new rules, i.e. `unique_together`. 
I recommend to take a backup of the database and then delete it. And run again the `makemigrations` and migrate command.

Answer (score 0):

So the error comes from the fact that in your serializer, you don't specify `object_id` in the meta fields.

By default all fields in a django model are required and do not accept null values.

If you want a field to be null, you need explicitly set `null=True` for the field in your model. But in your case, as it is part of the unique constraint, i don't expect that null is correct value.

Solution is to include the `object_id` in your serializer's fields.

You may send it in your post request but your serializer will ignore it as it is not in the list of fields to serialize.

That's why I asked you to include your POST data which you send.